# Using Js to change my style sheet for ipad?

Tags: javascript, media-queries, browser-detection, css

I currently have styles applied to my site that take effect when the screen is resized or when it's visited with an iphone, using CSS media queries. http://iamcreative.me

*The media-query*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 320px) and (orientation:portrait)" href="css/iphone.css" />
```

The problem I found was that once I created a stylesheet for an ipad's 720px portrait view, this would affect some of the styles that I created for the iphone!

I think this is because the iphone now has a screen resolution of 940px.

So this is what I came up with and wondered if this is the best way of getting round my problem?

*I create the function:*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function isiPad() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i); 
}
</script>
```

*Then in the page I add:*

```
if (isiPad()) { 
document.styleSheets[0].href="ipad.css";
}
else
{
document.styleSheets[0].href="everything-else.css";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the viewport size of the browser window, here is a good article I found that has solutions on what you are looking for.

[iPad/iPhone viewport settings](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/toolbox/article.php/3889591/Detect-and-Set-the-iPhone--iPads-Viewport-Orientation-Using-JavaScript-CSS-and-Meta-Tags.htm)

Comment: I have this in the head of my page, but it still effects the iphone styles                                                                          .content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=1.0;" />

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Screen queries: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ to define different styles for different devices.

Comment: Thanks.

That would be great except for that I have used media queries to define the style sheets.

But as I say in my question, the iPhone has a resolution of 940px so it is picking up the styles applied to the iPad. 

This is why I want to use JavaScript to detect the iPad specifically.